# I am facing issues while installing libsctp on redhat

Tags: linux, redhat, sctp

I am trying to install libsctp on redhat. There is a chain of dependencies. How to install all libraries/dependencies in this group?

configure: error: --with-sctp given but cannot find libsctp [root@localhost libfixbuf-1.7.1]# cd ../Downloads/ [root@localhost Downloads]# rpm -ivh libsctp1-1.0.11-4-mdv2012.0.i586.rpm warning: libsctp1-1.0.11-4-mdv2012.0.i586.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 26752624: NOKEY Preparing... ########################################### [100%] package libsctp1-1.0.11-4.i586 is already installed [root@localhost Downloads]#

I am trying to install libfixbuf using ./configure --with-sctp The error thrown says that sctp is not installed. though it is installed

Solved the issue.. Installed lksctp-tools-1.0.16. That solved the problem

Comment: Update the exact error message. It will easy to understand the problem.

Comment: [Try it out](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220503/how-to-install-dependencies-of-an-rpm-package-without-installing-the-package-its)

Comment: configure: error: --with-sctp given but cannot find libsctp
[root@localhost libfixbuf-1.7.1]# cd ../Downloads/
[root@localhost Downloads]# rpm -ivh libsctp1-1.0.11-4-mdv2012.0.i586.rpm
warning: libsctp1-1.0.11-4-mdv2012.0.i586.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 26752624: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
 package libsctp1-1.0.11-4.i586 is already installed
[root@localhost Downloads]#

Comment: I am trying to install libfixbuf

using ./configure --with-sctp

The error thrown says that sctp is not installed. though it is installed

Comment: Please include this in the question itself (not in the comments).

Comment: Solved the issue..

Installed lksctp-tools-1.0.16. That solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue.. Installed lksctp-tools-1.0.16. That solved the problem